# Why won't sampling at time intervals shorter than the detector's response provide new information?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

"*When Fourier analysing a signal, sampling at time intervals shorter than the detector's response won't provide any new information, only smoother data.*"

This was told to me, but I don't quite understand why this is so. I understand that the Fourier analysis of a signal consists on representing that same signal as a sum of simpler trignometric functions, but I don't understand why using shorter time intervals won't continuously provide more data.

Comment: The sensor only responds so fast - what additional information are you expecting to get?

Comment: If a detector can only update its measurement once per minute, how can you claim to sample the data at a rate of 10 times per minute?  In other words, how can you sample the data at a higher rate than the detector can provide updates, when in principle, a "sample" is a new detector reading?

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was clearly a misinterpretation of what was written as I thought that my statement meant something completely different.